# Design will not shown

Tags: expression-blend

in my system i have install expression-bland4 at that timen silverlight 4 was installed in my system. after that i am update Silverlight version 4 to 5. visual studio 2010 can create a project base on Silverlight5 but when i open that project in my expression bland it will loaded a project but not able to display xaml desin preview only text possion shown.
also when i create new project from expression bland will show only 3.0 and 4.0 version

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression Blend 4 does not support Silverlight 5 - you'll need to install Blend for Silverlight 5 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9503